# How to link a work item to a pull request using REST API in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

Within a release pipeline a new Pull Requested is created using REST API.

How to link a specific (already existing) Work Item to the Pull Request using REST API?

In the current version (DevOps 2019) it is not supported to link Work Items using [Pull Request API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0). (See also related [community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/569673/unable-to-link-work-items-to-pull-request-via-rest.html).)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using PowerShell the following snipped may help.

```
$requestUri = "$tfsCollectionUri/$teamProject/_apis/wit/workitems/$workItemId?api-version=5.0"
$json = '
[ {
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/relations/-",
  "value": {
    "rel": "ArtifactLink",
    "url": "$pullRequestArtifact",
    "attributes": { "name": "pull request" }
  }
} ]'
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $requestUri -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Method Patch -Body $json
```

Note, `$pullRequestArtifact` needs to be set. You can get it e.g. from [get request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#gitpullrequest).

Comment: Great !  You could accept this answer. It will be helpful to other users. Thanks.

Comment: I can "accept" my own answer. That is great.
Maybe you can vote my question/answer if you think it is correct, @KevinLu-MSFT?

Comment: Absolute hero. I had to make a few modifications (running on TFS 2018):
`-Method Patch` instead of Post, and
`api-version=4.1` instead of 5.0.
And this info was missing from this for me: `$pullRequestArtifact = "vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/$teamProject/$repositoryName/$pullRequestId"`

Comment: Thanks, @SvenS, you are right. I forgot to mention because I did not BUILD the artifact URI but GET it from previous request. I edited the text to mention this.

Comment: The pull request was added to the workitem. But unfortunatly, this does not add the wokritem to the pull request. And the pull request is still missing a workitem to complete the policy set on the branch. Manually it works both ways but not using the api

Comment: @Mariusz, this maybe a bug in your TFS/DevOps version. Normally such link is build automatically in both directions. My example works fine on DevOps 2019 (Dev17.M153.5). If it not works as expected you should ask at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=22

Comment: I'm on Dev18.M170.8.

Comment: @Ig2de Thanks, it works. The pull request was create with the VSTeam PSModule, I remove and changed it to API calls and the issue is not reproducible since.